# Why does MSTest fail to deploy some test input files when there are more than 128 tests?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, mstest

We run automated tests on a build server which uses Jenkins to check out the source code, build it and run the tests by invoking MSTest. Everything worked fine until we added the 129th unit test. Then some of the other tests mysteriously fail. The tests that do fail all require input files that should get deployed to the TestResults directory. However, those input files do not get deployed when a 129th test is added! Note that other tests also require input files but those do get deployed. There's no obvious reason as to why some test input files get deployed but others don't.

Things we've tried:

- It doesn't matter which test project the 129th unit test is added to or what is in the new test (for example: Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);)
- Run MSTest manually on the command line (Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools) on the build server whilst logged in as me. The same tests fail when there are more than 128 tests. So it's unlikely to be something to do with Jenkins or the fact that the automated tests run under a different user account (system).
- Copied the built code from the build server to my laptop and run the same MSTest command there. On my laptop all 129 tests pass, even though the build machine and my laptop are using the same version of MSTest (10.0.30319.1).

Has anyone else seen anything like this? It's got to be something which only occurs when more than 128 tests are added, and which can occur on one machine but not another! Is 128 a coincidence? I know it's a significant number in computing.

Comment: How are you running tests on the server?  Are you using `mstest.exe` or `vstest.console.exe`?

Comment: Cross-posted this issue on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c43574f0-f3af-450d-9767-10d9344cb3d8/mstest-is-failing-to-deploy-some-input-test-files-but-only-on-the-build-server-and-only-when-there?forum=vstest).

Comment: Sorry; just seen your comment - I'm using mstest.exe from VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation it looks like there is some issue with MSTest or some agent it calls under the covers. See the [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c43574f0-f3af-450d-9767-10d9344cb3d8/mstest-is-failing-to-deploy-some-input-test-files-but-only-on-the-build-server-and-only-when-there?forum=vstest) for details.

But when I installed Visual Studio 2013 on the build server machine, in addition to the VS2010 that was already installed, all 129 tests then would pass, both when running MSTest from the VS2010 command prompt and when run through Jenkins. Note that VS2013 is **not** used to build or run the tests; I've not even opened it up on the build server; just installed it!

So installing VS2013 affects the way MSTest for VS2010 will run. Maybe it patches MSTest or some agent it uses, or changes some environment variables, or ...?! So there's probably a shorter fix for this but the workaround for now is to install VS2013 on the machine in addition to VS2010 if you want to execute more than 128 tests using MSTest for VS2010. Surely Microsoft knows about this issue?!